# subplots forced to have same axis

Tags: python, plot, 3d, visualization

Recently I am plotting 2 graphs at a fig. The data is different and share no common contents. But the final visualizations are forced to have the same axis, I don't understand.

[Image  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOInx.png)

```
#################################################################################################
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharey = False, sharex = False)

c = list(len(mydf)*'b')
for i in range(len(c)):
    if mydf['percent'][i] > 0.05:
        c[i] = 'r'
# ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.bar(range(len(mydf['cdf'])), mydf['cdf'], color = c)
ax1.set_xticks(range(len(mydf['cdf'])))
ax1.set_xticklabels(list(mydf['3D_Attri']), rotation=45)

###########################################################################################3

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
xs = mydf['sphere']
ys = mydf['cylinder']
zs = mydf['addition']
ax2.scatter(xs, ys, zs, zdir='z', s=20, c=c, depthshade=True)
ax2.set_xlabel('sphere')
ax2.set_ylabel('cylinder')
ax2.set_zlabel('addition')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create two subplots in your first line of code. Place a `plt.show()` directly after that to see that there the wrong axis is already plotted. This will interfere with your 3D graph later, which you simply place on top of it. You have to approach this differently:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
##################################################################################
fig = plt.figure()

c = list(len(mydf)*'b')
for i in range(len(c)):
    if mydf['percent'][i] > 0.05:
        c[i] = 'r'
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.bar(range(len(mydf['cdf'])), mydf['cdf'], color = c)
ax1.set_xticks(range(len(mydf['cdf'])))
ax1.set_xticklabels(list(mydf['3D_Attri']), rotation=45)
##################################################################################
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
xs = mydf['sphere']
ys = mydf['cylinder']
zs = mydf['addition']
ax2.scatter(xs, ys, zs, zdir='z', s=20, c=c, depthshade=True)
ax2.set_xlabel('sphere')
ax2.set_ylabel('cylinder')
ax2.set_zlabel('addition')
plt.show()
```

Output from a toy data set:
[image]

Comment: If this solved your problem, feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).